# Tangent line to a surface

Tags: calculus, surfaces, tangent-line

I have to find the tangent line to the surface
$$z=\frac{x^{2}}{4}+\frac{y^{2}}{9}$$
at
$$P(2,-3,2)$$
such that this line pass through the $x$-axis.

I evaluated the directional derivative of $z$ in the direction of $\vec{u}=(2,-3)$ that is equal to
$$\frac{4}{\sqrt{13}}$$
and so, the line equation is
$$y+3=\frac{4}{\sqrt{13}}(x-2)$$
But I don't think this is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Find the plane tangent to the surface at the given point $P$. Such plane intersect the $x$-axis at $Q$. The line through $P$ and $Q$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: So obvious! haha thanks :)